# Remove gap before tabular

Tags: spacing

I was trying use this code in a document that contains text before and after this table, but I keep getting a large vertical gap before and after the table. How do I fix this?

```
\def\arraystretch{2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{23pt}

\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.7}{
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
    \toprule
    $n$ & $t_n$ & $y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})$                          & $y_n = y_{n-1} + (t_n - t_{n-1})y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})$  \\\midrule
    1 & 0       & --                                             & 1 \\
    2 & 0.2     & $-2\cdot1+1-e^0 = -2$                          & $1 + 0.2(-2) = 0.6$  \\
    3 & 0.4     & $-2\cdot0.6+ 1 - e^{-4\cdot0.2} \approx -0.65$ &   $0.6 + 0.2(-0.65) = 0.47$\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Don't use `\scalebox` on tables, this gives inconsistent fontsizes, spacing, etc.

Comment: also if you do use scalebox (and don't use it on tables) don't leave a space after the `{` and before the `}`

Answer (score 3):

Three main points to consider here. First, `\begin{center} .. \end{center}` adds a vertical space before and after the environment, use the `\centering` macro instead. Second, `\scalebox` is not recommended as pointed out by @skillmon, because it makes inconsistent font sizes that can be hard to read. Third, it is much better to use a `\table` environment and let LaTeX position the table at the optimum position. Lastly, you give `\arraystretch` and `\tabcolsep` huge values, let `booktabs` manage this beautifully.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\small
\centering
%\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
    \toprule
    $n$ & $t_n$ & $y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})$                      & $y_n = y_{n-1} + (t_n - t_{n-1})y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})$  \\\midrule
    1 & 0   & --                                             & 1 \\
    2 & 0.2 & $-2\cdot1+1-e^0 = -2$                          & $1 + 0.2(-2) = 0.6$  \\
    3 & 0.4 & $-2\cdot0.6+ 1 - e^{-4\cdot0.2} \approx -0.65$ & $0.6 + 0.2(-0.65) = 0.47$\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

remove:

```
 \def\arraystretch{2}
```

Comment: @Teepeemm why is this

Comment: arraystretch affects the space between lines of the table but not (directly) the space before or after the table. As you provided no example document it is impossible to comment on how this affects spacing in your case.